# React Native Swipeable Gesture Not Working (expo)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Mine react Native Gesture Is Not Working Here Goes My Code
I have installed the library with this command

```
$ expo install react-native-gesture-handler
```

Please help me with this issue:
how can I resolve this

code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Image, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight, View } from 
'react-native'
import Colors from '../config/Colors.js'
import AppText from './AppText/AppText.js'
import Swipeable from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable';


const HorizontalListitem = ({ image, title, subtitle, onPress, 
style, renderRightActions }) => {
return (

<Swipeable renderRightActions={() => (
  <View style={{ width: 80, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'red' 
}}></View>
)}>
  <TouchableHighlight
    underlayColor={Colors.lightgray}
    onPress={onPress}
    style={style}
  >
    <View style={styles.listContainer}>
      <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: image }}> 
</Image>
      <View style={styles.title}>
        <AppText style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{title} 
</AppText>
        <AppText style={styles.subtitle}>{subtitle}</AppText>
      </View>
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
</Swipeable >
)
}
```

Comment: You need to put a little bit more effort into your question.  What is the problem specifically?  What do you expect to happen vs. what is happening?  What have your tried to remedy your problem.  Dumping the code and saying it's not working is not going to get you much assistance in this forum.

Answer (score 4):

wrapping the swipeable with `{GestureHandlerRootView}` also helps

```
import Swipeable from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable';
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

<GestureHandlerRootView>

<Swipeable renderRightActions=...>

</Swipeable>

</GestureHandlerRootView>
```

Comment: Legend. This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

wrapping the swipeable with {GestureHandlerRootView} also helps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bakhK.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution: -**

```
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableHighlight } from "react-native";
import Swipeable from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable';

import AppText from "./AppText";
import colors from "../config/colors";

function ListItem({ title, subTitle, image, renderRightActions, onPress }) {
  return (
    <Swipeable renderRightActions={renderRightActions}>
      <TouchableHighlight 
          underlayColor={colors.light}
          onPress={onPress}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
              <Image style={styles.image} source={image}/>
              <View>
                  <AppText style={styles.title}>{title}</AppText>
                  <AppText style={styles.subTitle}>{subTitle}</AppText>
              </View>
          </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </Swipeable>
  );
}
```

**And in MessageScreen.js**

```
    <FlatList
        data={messages}
        keyExtractor={message => message.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem 
                title={item.name}
                subTitle={item.description}
                image={item.image}
                renderRightActions={() => (
                    <View style={{ width: 70, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'red' }}></View>
                )}
            />
        )}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={ListItemSeparator}
    />
```

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue when I'm using expo SDK 39. I couldn't sort it out. I tried upgrading it to v43 and it worked fine. [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@dnsamw/dnsam-swipeable) is a working expo snack I created for testing Swipeable.

Answer (score 0):

The api has changed. See docs below

```
import Swipeable from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable';
```

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/api/components/swipeable